# Returning external data from a function in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-2

I have the following script that is calling a text file:

```
    /* first create a new instance of the LoadVars object */
myVariables = new LoadVars();
myVariables.load("myFile.txt");
myVariables.onLoad = function(getreading):String{
    var ODOMETER2:String=myVariables.ACADEMICWATER;
    return ODOMETER2;
    trace (ODOMETER2);
}
trace(getreading());
```

The text file contains the following:

```
ACADEMICWATER=3002&elec=89
```

I am able to import the value of 3002 into the function and I can trace it. However, I *Should* be able to trace it outside the function using trace(getreading()); as shown on the last line. This only returns an "UNDEFINED" value.  I am stumped.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring an *anonymous function* (see [AS3 Syntax and language / Functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fd0.html)) which can't be referenced by name. `getreading` is declared in your code as an untyped parameter of this function.

If you want to `trace` the result of this function, then you should declare a *named function* like this:

```
function getReading(): String {
    var ODOMETER2:String=myVariables.ACADEMICWATER;
    return ODOMETER2;
}

myVariables.onLoad = getReading;

trace(getReading());
```

Answer (score 0):

`getreading` is not the name of the function in this case, but the name of a parameter to the anonymous function that is run on the onLoad event of the `myVariables` object.

Place the variable `ODOMETER2` outside the function and set it's value inside the anonymous function. Then you will be able to access it outside the function as well.

```
/* first create a new instance of the LoadVars object */ 
var ODOMETER2:String;
myVariables = new LoadVars(); 
myVariables.load("myFile.txt"); 
myVariables.onLoad = function(){ 
    ODOMETER2=myVariables.ACADEMICWATER; 
} 
trace(ODOMETER2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`LoadVars.onLoad` is an event handler. It is called by `LoadVars` as soon as it finishes with the asynchronous load operation. It takes a boolean argument, indicating success or failure of the operation. It does not return anything.

[LoadVars.onLoad documentation](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary433.html)

In that function, you typically act upon the data you received, like storing and processing it. Here's a very simple example showing some basic use cases:

```
var ODOMETER2:String;

var myVariables = new LoadVars();
myVariables.load("myFile.txt");
myVariables.onLoad = function(success) {
    trace(success);
    ODOMETER2 = myVariables.ACADEMICWATER;
    processResults();
}

function processResults() {
    trace(ODOMETER2);
    trace(myVariables.ACADEMICWATER);
}

// traces:
// true
// 3002
// 3002
```